# Regex find duplicate values in this set

Tags: c#, regex

I have an list of string values which looks like this:

```
GREEN,BLUE,BLUE
BLUE,BLUE,GREEN
GREEN,RED,RED
RED,BLUE,BLUE
BLUE,RED,RED
GREEN,BLUE,BLUE
RED,GREEN,BLUE
```

I will use a foreach to loop through each line and find unique values.

I need a regex that returns true is there are no color duplicates (RED,GREEN,BLUE) and false if there are color duplicates (RED,GREEN,RED).

What would the regex look like?

Comment: A regular expression doesn't seem like the best tool for the job... I would compare `Count` between a list and a distinct list.

Comment: @DeanFenster I've never used distinct lists. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You really would not like to use  `if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)")) {return true;}`

Comment: In the real world, something like this `\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)`. used on a list of 1,000 words, that are unique, would take about an hour to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* instead of *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...  

  string source = "BLUE,BLUE,GREEN";

  // do we have three distinct items?
  bool allDistinct = source.Split(',').Distinct().Count() >= 3;
```

Test:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {
  "GREEN,BLUE,BLUE",
  "BLUE,BLUE,GREEN",
  "GREEN,RED,RED",
  "RED,BLUE,BLUE",
  "BLUE,RED,RED",
  "GREEN,BLUE,BLUE",
  "RED,GREEN,BLUE",
};

var result = list
  .Select(source => $"{source,-15} {source.Split(',').Distinct().Count() >= 3}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
GREEN,BLUE,BLUE False
BLUE,BLUE,GREEN False
GREEN,RED,RED   False
RED,BLUE,BLUE   False
BLUE,RED,RED    False
GREEN,BLUE,BLUE False
RED,GREEN,BLUE  True
```

**Edit:** *Linq* can help out in the generalized case:

```
bool allDistinct = !source
  .Split(',')
  .GroupBy(item => item, (k, s) => s.Skip(1).Any())
  .Any(item => item);
```

Comment: That worked great, cheers!

Comment: I should really invest more time into learning more about Linq, a very powerful tool indeed!

Comment: @Json: You are welcome! Yes, Linq deserves studying ;)

Comment: If you want the logic to be invariant on the number of elements in the list, I believe you could do a GroupBy and then All making sure there is only one occurence of each element:
source.Split(',').GroupBy(e => e).All(e => e.Count() == 1))